# What do you believe was meant by FEA?

Tags: rf, radar

[image: FEA?]

[image: Figure 12]

( RCS =  radar cross section )

FEA wasn't mentioned in the acronyms or keywords list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"**F**inite **E**lement **A**nalysis"

Simulations that work over 3D surfaces by breaking everything up into a little triangular section, analyzing each one individually, and piecing everything together

Comment: Not all grids have to be triangular.. but spot on.